# How we override the vue-storefront components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-storefront

I am new to vue-storefront . Can anyone please explain how we override the vue-storefront components with example.Thank you

Comment: Maybe this section is what you're after? https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/core-themes/core-components.html#overriding-and-extending-core-components-and-pages

Comment: Hi Daniel , thanks for the response , can you please explain with any example.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: For example , In  vsf there is a component named <ONewsletter />, If we used inside the template means , it will display with 3 section ( title , subtitle and a subscribe buttton )  , now my question is , How I add another button in that same layout .

Comment: Can you please share the code of <ONewsletter />?

Answer (score 0):

You do not really want to override it. Overriding is a mechanism recommended if you want to change some core behavior (from `core` directory). As you want to modify component inside the Capybara theme - just do it. It is totally okay to do it inside without overriding.

To be precise, feel free to modify each file inside VSF1 PWA's `src` directory - I mean:

- src/modules/*
- src/search/*
- src/themes/*
- src/*.html